# Status in publishing queue stays on "Ready for transport" even for items that published successfully

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Whenever we are publishing any item from CMS its status is not showing success. It is stuck on to ready for transport. But actually items are getting published to CDS. Because of this status issue that code is not working well which checks the publish status of items.

Comment: So you are saying that the status of an item remains 'Ready for transport', but it actually IS published successfully? Are you sure that it's not a browser-caching issue with the Publish Queue?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. But it is not a browser-caching issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution.
On publisher in the Tridion bin folder there is a transaction folder. It was containing thousands of files. Every time when publishing done It seems these failed transactions were processed by publisher which was the issue of not showing the publishing status as Success. We deleted those files and now the things are getting success.

Answer (score 3):

Check what happens to one of the problematic transport package in the log files of the transport service and the deployer.

I've never seen anything what you describe here, but this is indeed the behavior you're seeing, something relevant is bound to show up there.